# What are 'pg_internal.init' files for?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

What are 'pg_internal.init' files for in PostgreSQL 9?

Those seem to be rewritten awfully often.

UPDATE:
It seems to be related to "relation cache". But why that cache is rebuilt every other millisecond?

Comment: `src/backend/utils/cache/relcache.c:#define RELCACHE_INIT_FILENAME "pg_internal.init"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using 9.1.18?  There was a bug introduced in 9.1.18 which caused unnecessary traffic on that file.  It was fixed in 9.1.19.

Comment: It's very nice of them not to mention that in relnotes. :)

Comment: The fix to the bug is in the 9.1.19 release notes under `Fix insertion of relations into the relation cache "init file"`.  The introduction of the bug isn't in the 9.1.18 release notes, of course....

Answer (score 1):

pg_internal.init is a file in the data directory which contains the relation cache (Each pg_internal.init contains up to 100 Relation entries of System Catalogs). A file exists in the global subdirectory, and one in each database subdirectory and possibly in each non-default tablespace.

Each pg_internal.init file is removed at postmaster startup, and recreated by the first backend which is launched.

https://pgpedia.info/p/pg_internal-init.html